# remove an element from global click event done on the whole html body

Tags: jquery, event-handling, fadein, fadeout

I am running this program to appear and disappear a list item using fadein and fadeout.
until this its working fine the problem is that i need to make it so that the list not to disappear when clicked on the list.

```
$( "html :not(.notthis,button)" ).click(function(event) {
  $( "#fade" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
 });

http://jsfiddle.net/revanth1991/6k4nf5v5/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the clicked element in jQuery using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). Check out the demo on that page to understand the hierarchy.
You need to check whether the `event.target.className` is not equal to "notthis".

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2cvbo6j/) with what you want.